# DSP48 on FPGA need extra clock cycles to be ready?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, xilinx, dsp

When I use ISim of ISE14.7 to simulate a DSP48A1-based multiplier, the DSP output signal (dsp_o) of the sequence diagram always starts with many '0' outputs. This results in the loss of some of the initial product results.

My code and sequence diagram are as follows.

```
module tb_dsp();

    reg clk;
    reg rst;
    wire [27:0] dsp_o;
    
    reg [12:0] a_i = 3;
    reg [12:0] b_i = 3;

    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        #5
        forever
            #5
            clk = ~clk;
    end
    
    initial begin
        rst = 0;
          #10
          rst = 1;
          #40
          rst = 0;
        #16000 
        $stop;
    end
    
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        a_i <= a_i+1;
        b_i <= b_i+1;
    end

     MULT_MACRO #(
      .DEVICE("SPARTAN6"), // Target Device: "VIRTEX5", "VIRTEX6", "SPARTAN6" 
      .LATENCY(3),        // Desired clock cycle latency, 0-4
      .WIDTH_A(14),       // Multiplier A-input bus width, 1-18
      .WIDTH_B(14)        // Multiplier B-input bus width, 1-18
   ) MULT_MACRO_inst (
      .P(dsp_o),     // Multiplier output bus, width determined by WIDTH_P parameter 
      .A({1'b0,a_i}),     // Multiplier input A bus, width determined by WIDTH_A parameter 
      .B({1'b0,b_i}),     // Multiplier input B bus, width determined by WIDTH_B parameter 
      .CE(1'b1),   // 1-bit active high input clock enable
      .CLK(clk), // 1-bit positive edge clock input
      .RST(rst)  // 1-bit input active high reset
   );
    
endmodule
```

[image: Sequence diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the sequence diagram always starts with many '0' outputs.

It is because, the Multiplier block you use is a [pipelined design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipelining_(DSP_implementation)) to increase the throughput. Every pipelined design has an initial latency, after which you get the outputs every clock cycle.

The latency is what you have configured during the instantiation:

```
.LATENCY(3),
```

As you can see the output for `12 x 12 @90ns` appeared after 3 clock cycles as `144 @120ns`.

The output for `13x13 @100ns` appeared as `169 @130ns`, and so on................

If you don't want this latency, you can configure it to lower value (I guess 0 is also supported, in that case it will be  a purely combinational logic). But lowering it will affect the timing performance of the core as it removes the fifo/register stages between the pipeline stages, thereby reducing the maximum achievable frequency of operation and hence throughput.

---

**Sidenote**:

Curious how the reset was pulled down @50 ns but the outputs for the inputs from 50 ns i.e., `8, 9, 10, 11` never appeared at the outputs. It is probably because of the global reset mechanism. See this extract from page 13 of [Synthesis Guide UG-900](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_3/ug900-vivado-logic-simulation.pdf)

> Apply stimulus data after 100 ns to account for the default Global Set/Reset (GSR) pulse
> used in functional and timing-based simulation.

So maybe that's why your stimuli before 100 ns were not sampled, as it was in reset state.